# how to change apk file name in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, android-manifest

I am using android studio to make android application. Android studio generating .apk file with default name app-debug.apk. I have tried to change it. How I change it?

Answer (score 4):

I found a very simple solution. The apk base name is the property archivesBaseName defined on the project. So the following line is enough to rename the apks:

```
project.archivesBaseName = "AnotherName";
```